# Messenger not working if using processor on same resource in APIPlatform 3.1

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I am using API Platform 3.1. I need to generate thumbnails on some entities after creation. I want to use [Symfony Messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html) to trigger this and do it asynchronously since it could take time some to process, but I want the entity to be saved immediately.

When a resource uses both the messenger and a custom processor (to save the entity), either the messages are not created if using `messenger=true`, or the processor is not called if using `messenger='input'`.

**How to reproduce**

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Post(
            processor: MyEntityProcessor::class,
            messenger: 'input',
            deserialize: false, 
        )
    ]
)]
class MyEntity
{
}
```

```php
final class MyEntityProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    public function __construct(private ProcessorInterface $persistProcessor)
    {
    }

    public function process($data, Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = [])
    {
        $result = $this->persistProcessor->process($data, $operation, $uriVariables, $context);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

```php
final class MyEntityHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
    }

    public function __invoke(MyEntity $myEntity)
    {
        // my long running function

        $this->entityManager->persist($myEntity);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

**services.yaml**

```yaml
services:
    App\State\MyEntityProcessor:
        bind:
            $persistProcessor: '@api_platform.doctrine.orm.state.item_provider'
```

**messenger.yaml**

```yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async: 'doctrine://default'

        routing:
            'App\Entity\MyEntity': async
```

API Platform documentation mentions in [Symfony Messenger Integration](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/messenger/#dispatching-a-resource-through-the-message-bus):

> Note: when using `messenger=true` ApiResource attribute in a Doctrine entity, the Doctrine Processor is not called. If you want the Doctrine Processor to be called, you should [decorate a built-in state processor](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/state-processors#decorating-the-built-in-state-processors) and implement your own logic.

It was [suggested on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/5772) that I should decorate the messenger handler in order to save the entity. However, I need my entity to be saved immediately without waiting for it to be consumed by the `messenger:consume` worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution would be to dispatch the `Message` in your `Processor` after you have persisted the `Entity` for the first time. Maybe not as clean, since it requires more code, however you have way more control over how and when the `Message` is handled. In addition, you could also dispatch it with a [`DelayStamp`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#envelopes-stamps).

In your processor I would [dispatch the `Message`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#dispatching-the-message) like this:

```
final class MyEntityProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    
    public function __construct(
        private ProcessorInterface $persistProcessor,
        private MessageBusInterface $bus,
    ) {
    }

    public function process($data, Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = [])
    {
        $result = $this->persistProcessor->process($data, $operation, $uriVariables, $context);

        // $data should be your MyEntity Entity.
        $this->bus->dispatch(new GenerateThumbMessage($data), [
            // wait 5 seconds before processing
            new DelayStamp(5000),
        ]);
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```

[Create the `Message`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#creating-a-message-handler) `App\Message\GenerateThumbMessage.php`:

```
class GenerateThumbMessage
{

    public function __construct(private readonly MyEntity $myEntity) {}

    public function getMyEntity(): MyEntity
    {
        return $this->myEntity;
    }

}
```

And then [create your `MessageHandler`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#creating-a-message-handler) `App\Message\GenerateThumbMessageHandler.php`:

```
final class GenerateThumbMessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $em) {}

    public function __invoke(GenerateThumbMessage $generateThumbMessage)
    {
        $myEntity = $generateThumbMessage->getMyEntity();
        
        // your long running function to generate a thumbnail

        $this->em->persist($myEntity);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Your `messenger.yaml` config should look something like this:

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async: 'doctrine://default'

        routing:
            'App\Message\GenerateThumbMessage': async
```

In the config, in stead of using the `Entity`, you have configured the `Message` to be processed async.

A similary solution can be found in the [API Platform documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/state-processors/#hooking-into-the-built-in-state-processors)